# Inserting images and text into SQLite database in android

Tags: android, image, sqlite

dear programmers!
My question is about inserting data in SQLite, in such a way that there are four five items of spinner(dropdown list)
for any item of spinner there is a table in database, the tables are:
1- lcd
2- crt
3- dish => short form of dish antenna
4- antenna
5- cd_dvd_player
I have determined  the algorithm in such a way when i choose any item of spinner, the data of the item should be inserted in its related table
like; above five tables, but toast message shows wrong data inserted while in fact is not inserted. The codes are as following:
if you answer my question, you would have helped a lot thanks a lot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVU63.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In short you are likely going to encounter numerous issues if you try to store large images in the Database.

The recommended way is to store the images as files and store the paths or part of the paths in the Database, using the stored path to access the images when required.

It very much appears that the screen shot is related to exceeding memory limitations.